# Firebase notification delays when calling it from my server side

Tags: c#, android, .net, windows-services, firebase-notifications

I am implementing firebase notification in my project
when I use this call from Post Man it delivers in real time even when the phone is in doze mode.

```
{    
        "to":"***************************************************************",
        "notification":{
            "title":"Welcome",
            "body":"hard push",
            "image":"",
            "sound":"default"
        },
        "priority":10,
        "android": {
        "priority": "high"
    }   
}
```

but when I'm calling it in my windows service as

```
string jsonString = "{\"to\":\""+ token +"\", \"notification\":{ \"title\":\""+ title +"\", \"body\":\""+ body +"\", \"image\":\""+ img +"\" }, \"priority\":10 , \"android\": { \"priority\": \"high\" }}";
streamWriter.Write(jsonString);
```

I get the response, the notification is also delivered but there is delay of 2 to 10 minutes when phone is in doze mode. API call is going on time as I have checked in logs. after the API call is successful and get the response success= 1 after that it delays, can't understand why this is happening

when the notification is delaying if I push notification from POST Man than it delivers immediately.

Need Solution

Comment: Because of battery saving notifications and other actions are never delivered in real time. A delay of some minutes is expected behavior on modern Android devices.

Comment: than how Whats app and other social media apps are working with real time? even for real time messaging